# Why is this covariant override permitted if the method is concrete, but not if abstract?

Tags: java

In the following code, `MoreSpecificHasInfo.getInfo()` is not permitted as an override by the Sun Java 5/6 compilers, saying, "`types IHasSpecialInfo and AbstractHasInfo are incompatible; both define getInfo(), but with unrelated return types`", although it compiles without error under Eclipse 3.4.2.  Also, if I replace the abstract implementation of `getInfo()` with the commented concrete version, it compiles fine everywhere.

I'm wondering which (if any) of the Sun or Eclipse compilers are in line with the [Java Language Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/), and if the Sun's compiler is correct, why is this not permitted?

```
interface IInfo {

}

interface ISpecialInfo extends IInfo {

}

interface IHasInfo {

    IInfo getInfo();

}

interface IHasSpecialInfo extends IHasInfo {

    ISpecialInfo getInfo();

}

abstract class AbstractHasInfo implements IHasInfo {

    public abstract AbstractInfo getInfo();

    abstract class AbstractInfo implements IInfo {

    }

}

abstract class MoreSpecificHasInfo extends AbstractHasInfo implements IHasSpecialInfo {

    @Override
    abstract public MoreSpecificInfo getInfo();

    //    @Override
    //    public MoreSpecificInfo getInfo() {
    //        return null;
    //    }

    abstract class MoreSpecificInfo extends AbstractHasInfo.AbstractInfo implements ISpecialInfo {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the issue correctly, [it's a bug in Java](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6294779). The bug status says that a fix is delivered but it's not at least in Java 6.

Comment: I believe that the bug database is saying that the fix is in the JDK 7 beta in build 31.

Comment: I think the bug to which you refer is concerned with interfaces.  The interfaces in @Matt R's example compile.

Comment: Thanks, yes, just tried this in the JDK 7 snapshot and it's been fixed. Certainly, the proposed solution in the bug evaluation covers this example too, "javac should be modified so that if a given pair of supertypes (Sj, Sk) indeed contains a pair of incompatible member (m1,m2), the site symbol should be checked for a symbol m3 overriding both m1 and m2."